# Kotlin using or in a paramater?

Tags: android, kotlin, functional-programming, overloading

I have two functions and two arrays. the functions and arrays do the same exact thing and look exactly the same except one takes in a string and one takes in a spanable string.

they look kind of like this:

```
private fun createTextView(randomText: String): View {
        tv = TextView(context)
        val linearLevel1: LinearLayout.LayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        tv.layoutParams = linearLevel1
        tv.gravity = Gravity.END
        tv.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.blogger_sans_medium)
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25f)
        tv.text = randomText
        return tv
    }
    private fun createTextView(randomText: SpannableStringBuilder): View {
        tv = TextView(context)
        val linearLevel1: LinearLayout.LayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        tv.layoutParams = linearLevel1
        tv.gravity = Gravity.END
        tv.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.blogger_sans_medium)
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25f)
        tv.text = randomText
        return tv
    }
```

and the two arrays look like this

```
private var textViewArr = ArrayList<String>()
private var textViewArrSpan = ArrayList<SpannableStringBuilder>()
```

Anyway I can combine these? Can i make a a function take parameter A or B or a variable be initialized with A or B? I tried searching online and I saw places that suggested I do what I already had done. wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [`SpannableStringBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder) implement [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html), and reading the documentation for [`TextView.setText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)), it takes a `CharSequence` as well.

So I think you can just do this:

```
private fun createTextView(randomText: CharSequence): View {
    tv = TextView(context)
    val linearLevel1: LinearLayout.LayoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    tv.layoutParams = linearLevel1
    tv.gravity = Gravity.END
    tv.typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.blogger_sans_medium)
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25f)
    tv.text = randomText
    return tv
}
```

Not critical but related, we can make this an expression as well...

```
private fun createTextView(randomText: CharSequence): View =
    TextView(context).apply {
        layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        gravity = Gravity.END
        typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.blogger_sans_medium)
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25f)
        text = randomText
   }
```

Comment: this did the trick! and thank you for the expression tip. I had no idea you could do that

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change type of `randomText` from `String` or `SpannableStringBuilder` to [CharSequence](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence)